# Reformatting an XML with IntelliJ

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, formatting, reformatting

I have an XML file with many tags that are clumped together, rather than being separated by \r\n.  When I try to use IntelliJ to reformat the code using the reformat code command, it doesn't automatically split `<tag1><tag2>` into 
`<tag1>
<tag2>`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to add significant whitespace within a tag? `<tag1><tag2>` is not the same as `<tag1> <tag2>`

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to do a line break (\r\n)